# Jquery: not removing rows from html table

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, removeclass

I have a html table and I need to remove some rows according to the ids passed by a function.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <script>
    function myfunc(){
        var dat ="6|21|22|"; // this string is a dynamic string coming 
                             // from another function. I've hardcoded it 
                             // for clarity
        var aryDat0 = dat.split('|');
        //delete empty elements
        var aryDat = aryDat0.filter(function(v){return !!v}); 
        for (var i = 0, l = aryDat.length; i <l; i++) {
          $( "'#" + aryDat[i] + "'" ).remove();
        }
    }
    </script>
    <table name="mytab" border="1px">
        <tr id="6"> 
            <td>6</td>
            <td>ada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="21">
            <td>21</td>
            <td>eda</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="22">
            <td>22</td>
            <td>ida</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="test" 
           onclick="javascript:myfunc(); return false;">
</html>
```

When I press the "test" button, nothing happens and  I get in Chrome's Console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#6'
```

Why?? 
If instead of:

```
$( "'#" + aryDat[i] + "'" ).remove();
```

I do:

```
$('#21').remove();
```

It works great.

Comment: First way to debug code is to write clean one! I edited your post code for better readability!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error ***Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#6'*** clearly states that `$("'#6'")` is an invalid Jquery selector

Try,

```
$( "#" + aryDat[i]).remove();
```

Comment: The `+ ""` is certainly very useful.

Comment: hahaha, great! thanks a ton! I'llbe acepting your answer in a moment. Thanks again!

Comment: @dystroy MR.OP, please don't note that.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate id value to  #

```
 $( '#' + aryDat[i]  ).remove();
```